# DynamoDB: Do we need ODM with Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

if we want to develop ERP using Amazon services. is the DynamoDB right choice.
and do we need to use any ODM like mongoose for mongo db.
i found vogels [enter link description here](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels) but it doesnt give much documentation not sure if its usable.
any suggestions are appriciated

Answer (score 3):

> is the DynamoDB right choice

There's no way to answer that question given the limited details you have provided. It may certainly work for you, but you will need to determine what your requirements are and make sure that they fit within the limitations of DynamoDB.

> do we need to use any ODM

You never "need" to use an ODM or ORM tool when interacting with a database. Obviously people are able to use databases before ODM or ORM tools are created for those databases. You may want to use an ODM library for interacting with DynamoDB to speed up development, but that is entirely up to you. I would look at the [AWS DynamoDB Document Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) that is included in the [AWS SDK for NodeJS](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) before looking at any third-party tools.